TypeScript type for functions that only accept an object type
Is there a way to define a TypeScript type where only functions taking a single object argument are assignable to it? For example:
type RestrictToObjectParam = any; // TODO

let fun: RestrictToObjectParam;
fun = (arg: object) => {};                 // OK
fun = (arg: {}) => {};                     // OK
fun = (arg: {str: string}) => {};          // OK
fun = (arg: {obj: {}, num: number}) => {}; // OK
fun = (arg: number) => {};                 // ERROR

Something like (arg: object) => any won't work because the third example isn't assignable to it. I've tried other things like:

<T extends object>(arg: T) => any to constrain the argument type
T extends object ? (arg: T) => void : never to distribute the argument type

but those seem to just boil down to (arg: object) => any.
Is this possible? I might be misunderstanding how function types in TypeScript work in general.

There is no such specific type and such a type would be unusable (what would you do with it? You can't call it because you don't know which object type it takes, such information is no longer present). You can make a generic type and use a helper function to verify that a value is assignable to it, as shown in this playground link (and that has the advantage of keeping track of the actual information that lets you call the function). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a duplicate; if not, what's missing?

This is caused by function parameter bivariance when comparing function types. The compiler option strictFunctionTypes is true by default in strict mode, but you can set it to false in order to achieve the desired compatibility behavior — however, please note the caveat in the documentation:

Function Parameter Bivariance
When comparing the types of function parameters, assignment succeeds if either the source parameter is assignable to the target parameter, or vice versa. This is unsound because a caller might end up being given a function that takes a more specialized type, but invokes the function with a less specialized type. In practice, this sort of error is rare, and allowing this enables many common JavaScript patterns.

TS Playground
type RestrictToObjectParam = (arg: object) => any;

let fun: RestrictToObjectParam;
fun = (arg: object) => {}; // Ok
fun = (arg: {}) => {}; // Ok
fun = (arg: { str: string }) => {}; // Ok
fun = (arg: { obj: {}; num: number }) => {}; // Ok
fun = (arg: number) => {}; /* Error
~~~
Type '(arg: number) => void' is not assignable to type 'RestrictToObjectParam'.
  Types of parameters 'arg' and 'arg' are incompatible.
    Type 'object' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2322) */

